# Error connecting

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We've got an .Net 1.1 asp.net application which was originally created to use SQL Server 2005.  The application uses Microsoft Application Block database access, it's installed on a virtual machine with Windows 2003 Server, and the Database on another VM.  We are now trying to migrate the database to SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows 2008 R2.  When the application runs, it gets the following error:

System.InvalidOperationException: The stored procedure 'StoredProcedureName' doesn't exist.

After a deep search, we found this page:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2706519/en-us

We installed the hot-fix as indicated, but the error remains.

--

Current configurations:

**Web server**:

- Windows Server 2003 on VMware

**Database server**

- Windows 2008 R2 on VMWare
- SQL Server 2008 R2

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're pointing to a correct database?

Comment: Is the stored procedure in question a CLR stored procedure?

Comment: Yes, we're pointing to the correct database.

Comment: How do we know if the SP is CLR or not?